# Auto Sends GPS Coordinates via SMS

Tags: android, gps, sms

I made an Application that shows my GPS coordinates (Langitude and Latitude) number, which designed with out a map. But I would like to send the lat and long to mobile number/phone number Automatically (no need a send button) every time I open this Application. Anyone can help me..

**Gps.java**

```
package Sample.gps.send;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gps extends Activity
{
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);


/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();


mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);


}


/* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();
String Text = "My location is: " +

"Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +

"Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();




Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
"GPS Disabled",


Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}


@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),


"GPS Enabled",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{


}

}

}
```

Here is for the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="Sample.gps.send"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".UseGps"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>          
          </activity>            
             </application> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>          
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>             
          </manifest>
```

Here MyLocationListener is an inner class. Can anyone tell how to retrieve the coordinates whenever onLocationChanged method is called? The location is displayed using a Toast. Is it possible to get the coordinates by calling any method from onCreate()?

Answer (score 1):

See, http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android. That tutorial will show you how to send an SMS, using that you should be able to figure out what you need to do.

Please use the code tags when posting code samples :-)